# Flash Builder Burrito - Skinning the ActionBar

Tags: android, apache-flex, android-actionbar, flex4.5, skin

I'm developing an application for Android using Burrito, and I came across a certain situation that I can't seem to find out how to solve. Which is, how do you change the ActionBar look and feel?

I can create a skin with the class ActionBar as its host component but (I hate buts so much) how do you actually use it then? How do you apply it to a view? It's just because I want to change its height. I don't really see any problem in it but my boss wants it smaller, so how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

1) Try to change the look&feel with css color schemes such as backgroundColor, color, ... (full list here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f85.html)
3) If you need more advanced styling/skinning, good luck because mobile skins have been developped fully with AS3 and looking at the default ActionBarSkin, it looks scary :)

Comment: here you can take a look at the AS class http://opensource.adobe.com/svn/opensource/flex/sdk/trunk/frameworks/projects/mobiletheme/src/spark/skins/mobile/ActionBarSkin.as